# Symfony2 - update entity with form errors

Tags: symfony, entity

I have a form to update a single user, the ID is passed in the url. I am logged in and I have a menu listing the registered users (with the property username).
This property should not be blank but when I update the entity and leave the username field empty, it's updated in my menu but I don't why. I have the message telling the username field should not be left blank and `$form->isValid()` return false.

Can somebody tell me something about this ? And how to solve the problem ? (or at least give me some advices)

Here is the code of my controller :

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('TasksUserBundle:User')
        ->findWithTasks($id);
    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Cet utilisateur n\'extiste pas');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Vos données ont été enregistrées');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tasks_user_view', ['id' => $id]));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'TasksUserBundle:User:view.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $user
        ]
    );
}
```

And the controller used to retrieve my user list in my menu :

```
public function userMenuAction()
{
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('TasksUserBundle:User')
        ->findAll();
    return $this->render(
        'TasksUserBundle:User:menu.html.twig', [
            'users' => $users,
            'route' => $this->get('request')->get('route'),
            'user_id' => $this->get('request')->get('id')
        ]
    );
}
```

Tell me if I need to add some informations

Answer (score 0):

You must reinitialize your form somewhere between

```
$form->handleRequest($this->get('request'));
```

and

```
$form->createView()
```

because like you have it, even if the form is not valid, the returned view is rendered using the invalid request data.

Comment: Yes to see the user clearly where are its errors. But my real problem is why the username in my menu change while I am editing that user (with errors in form) and nothing have been flushed by the ORM ?